# Create a Metal Window Wrapper using Objective-C++

Tags: c++, game-engine, metal, objective-c++, bridging-header

I am currently developing a lightweight game engine in C++ however I am developing on a Mac. Originally, I was using Bootcamp however I wanted to try to implement it on Mac using premake. I want to implement some Metal support into my engine and I know I need to use Objective-C++. Is there any way I can create a metal window in Objective-C++ and tie it into my C++ Code?

Comment: This is certainly possible. For example, the [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) project includes a C API that manages Cocoa objects (including `NSWindow`s) via an Objective-C backend implementation. In C++, you might use the [Pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) to create a pure C++ class that has an Objective-C++ implementation behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an existing Metal wrapper library for C++, https://github.com/naleksiev/mtlpp (MIT licensed). I don't have any personal experience with it yet, so I can't *recommend* it as such, but the code looks simple enough that if you ran into any problems or limitations with it you could probably fix them or extend it without much trouble.

There's an example which also creates a window, so at least the basics of that are covered: https://github.com/naleksiev/mtlpp/blob/master/examples/04_window.cpp

As @warrenm has pointed out in the comments, the key to creating "glue" between Objective-C and C++ is to keep the headers "clean" by not having any Objective-C keywords or types (outside of those defined in the *runtime* headers) in them.

Comment: I know what the mtlpp library is but what I was curious about is how does it avoid using any storyboard or xib files?

Comment: @James51332 You can create an `NSWindow` programmatically and add and arrange `NSView`s within it entirely in code. This part very much needs to be written in Objective-C, however. MTLPP appears to implement this [in this part of the code](https://github.com/naleksiev/mtlpp/blob/71a38f4e8bcf7a06bdb234cbe13c6299a9bb127e/examples/window_macos.mm#L27).

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the Pimpl Idiom. I can use that along with this tutorial: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/building-cocoa-applications/0596002351/ch04.html (with MTKView) to create a c++ rendering system for my engine. I also looked through the mtlpp and it's very useful. I now know how to wrap my objective-c code into my c++ code. I can now implement Mac support into my engine!

Answer (score 0):

I've learned over the past few months I've actually learned about the linker and that I can write a wrapper around Metal to fit my API quite easily. Here is simple example to log in using NSLog in c++.

Main.cpp

```
// Prototype (should probably be in a header)
// extern "C" to avoid name mangling
extern "C" void log(const char*);

int main() {
    log("This was printed in c++ using NSLog!!");
}
```

Log.m

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

void log(const char* str)
{
    NSLog(@(str));
}
```